# C - Printing combinations in an array or list

Tags: c, arrays, printing, permutation

I made a program that takes a string of characters, and prints out all the possible combinations of them. However, is there a way to record each combo in a list or an array instead of just printing them on screen? Because I need to be able to manipulate some of the combos rather than just looking at them.

```
void swap( char *a, char *b ){
    char tmp;
    tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

void permutation( char *c, int d, int e ){
    int f;

    if( d == e )
        printf( "%s\n", c );
    else{
        for( f = d; f <= e; f++ ){
            swap( ( c + d ), ( c + f ) );
            permutation( c, d + 1, e );
            swap( ( c + d ), ( c + f ) );
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    char wordInput[25];
    int len, arrLen, f;

    printf( "\nEnter text: " );
    gets( wordInput );
    len = strlen( wordInput );
    arrLen = len - 1;

    permutation( wordInput, 0, arrLen );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: let's say we have a word that's `k` letters long then the number of permutations would be `k! = k(k-1)(k-2)...(3)(2)(1)`  so you would need an array of strings (each k letters long) which is the size k! So  first figure out the length using strlen, then use malloc to allocate the array, then run through the permutations using whatever you like (recursion is okay) to fill up the array and voila.  Attempt to create a program using this hint. If you have trouble, will help further :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change permuation() to the following:

```
int permutation( char *c, int d, int e, int n, char **permuted_strings)
```

where n is the index of the next unused element in your array permuted_strings.  permuted_strings should be an array of k! elements if your string has length k, as indicated in a comment.  If your condition (d == e) is met, then you should save the string at permuted_strings[n] and increment n by 1 and return this value as the new value for n.  The permutation() function should always return the current value of n, and n should be reset to the return value of permutation() when it is called, so that subsequent calls to permutation() know the correct value of n, i.e. where to store the next string.